# Unable to Extract the Zip file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have tried to extract files from a zip container, but my script does not returns the below error

Error Details:

> format error: bad signature: 0x00000000 at offset 568276 in file
>   AUS-000X-201512 28234755_Data.zip at C:/Perl64/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line
>   477.Archive::Zip::_readSignature('IO::File=GLOB(0x2a5e2a8)', 'AUS-000X-20151228234755_Data.zip') called at
>   C:/Perl64/lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 603
>   Archive::Zip::Archive::readFromFileHandle('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x32c1e8)',
>   'IO::File=GLOB(0x2a5e2a8)', 'AUS-000X-20151228234755_Data.zip') called
>   at C:/Perl64/lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 548
>   Archive::Zip::Archive::read('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x32c1e8)',
>   'AUS-000X-20151228234755_Data.zip') called at zip_extraction.pl line
>   14 Read of AUS-000X-20151228234755_Data.zip failed

```
use strict;

use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES);

opendir( DIR, "C:\\Users\\vinayas1\\Desktop\\Automation" ) || die "Can't
+ open local directory : $!";
my @zips = grep { -f "./$_" } readdir(DIR);
close(DIR);

foreach my $zipfiles ( grep( /\.zip$/, @zips ) ) {

    print "$zipfiles\n";

    if ( $zipfiles =~ /\w+\.zip$/ ) {

        my $zip     = Archive::Zip->new();
        my $zipName = "$zipfiles";
        my $status  = $zip->read($zipName);

        die "Read of $zipName failed\n" if $status != AZ_OK;

        print "$zipfiles\n";
        $zip->extractTree();

        #unlink($zipfiles);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried unzipping the same file "manually"? Do you get the same error? In that case the file is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

> format error: bad signature: 0x00000000 at offset 568276

This probably means that the file is corrupt. ZIP signatures end with 0x4b50 little endian but in your case it reads 0x0000 which indicates that the file does not conform to the ZIP specification.